# Why it is not advisable to use Compare() method with parameters in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Why it is not advisable to use Compare() method with parameters (for example StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) in EF Core?

I've tried an implementation like this:

```
var searchString = "abc";     
var result = items.Where(t => t.Name.ToString().Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

`items` here are IQueryable

Actualy this code works, but I'm not sure if it does not have any pitfalls. I will provide a profiling results of how it executes on the SQL side tomorrow.

Comment: Does the RDBMS offer an ordinal insensitive contains operation? If not: it is going to be a per-row case conversion at best (or: fetch everything over the network and evaluate in managed code, at worst). Either way: "contains"  (`like` etc): isn't great for index usage.

Comment: You should have waited for the profiling result. It will answer your question. Also, if you have some source that advises against it, doesn't the same source offer an explanation?

Comment: *Actualy this code works* - how quickly, on a million rows?